# GROUP BY a key and select the one with the highest value on another key

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've got a MySQL Table with the following structure

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | incident | message |
+----+----------+---------+
| 1  | 3        | 1       |
| 2  | 3        | 2       |
| 3  | 5        | 1       |
| 4  | 6        | 0       |
| 5  | 6        | 4       |
| 6  | 6        | 1       |
| 7  | 7        | 1       |
| 8  | 7        | 2       |
+----+----------+---------+
```

This is simplified data, but it's the same thing.

What I want is `GROUP BY` `incident` but only fetch those rows with the highest `message` value.

So taken the data above I want to fetch the following `id`s: `2, 3, 5, 8`

I did a `GROUP BY incident ORDER BY message` statement, but that didn't work. I'm not very familiar with the grouping stuff in MySQL, so it would be great if you can help me out here.

Comment: `+1` for adding sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query has *subquery* which gets the *maximum* `message` for each `incident`. The result of it is then join against theoriginal table itself based on two conditions, that it matched with the `incident` and the `message`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT incident, MAX(message) maxM
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY incident
        ) b ON a.incident = b.incident AND
                a.message = b.maxM
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94314/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY message DESC) AS A 
GROUP BY incident
```